# Not able to install Shiny latest version in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have r version 3.5.3 & RStudio version 1.1.463 installed. I installed shiny to run a basic shiny app using command `install.packages("shiny")`.After when I run the app it says[image]

Please advise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you-

Tools--> Global Options --> General--> R Version

wrong R Version was selected. #fail